# Convert a key-value array with duplicate keys into array of object with unique key, and value array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I have an array of key/value pairs. The keys are sometimes duplicated, and the values are always unique per key.
I want to condense each unique key to an object, so that I have a key and an array of the associated values as a property.
Are there any handy javascript functions to do this?

This

```
pairArray = [
{ key: "a", value: "1" },
{ key: "a", value: "2" },
{ key: "b", value: "1" },
{ key: "b", value: "2" },
];
```

Becomes

```
objectArray = [
{ key: "a", values: ["1", "2"] },
{ key: "(", values: ["1", "2"] }
];
```

Comment: So, what you tried?

Comment: Edit your question and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a map using `Array.reduce()` with your `key` property of your object as key of your map, `Object.values()` on that map will give you the desired result :

Assuming you have a typo in your expected output. You can try the following :

```js
const pairArray =  [ { key: "a", value: "1" }, { key: "a", value: "2" }, { key: "b", value: "1" }, { key: "b", value: "2" }, ];

const result = Object.values(pairArray.reduce((acc, {key, value})=>{
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {key, values : []};
  acc[key].values.push(value);
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because is identical to your answer.. Although it has not been copied ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map()` to get the desired output:

```js
let data = [
  { key: "a", value: "1" },
  { key: "a", value: "2" },
  { key: "b", value: "1" },
  { key: "b", value: "2" },
];

let reducer = arr => {
    let map = new Map();

    arr.forEach(({key:k, value:v}) => {
        let values = map.get(k) || [];
        values.push(v);
        map.set(k, values);
    });

    return [...map.entries()].map(([k, v]) => ({key: k, values: v}));
};

console.log(reducer(data));
```