# Not able to apply the spread operator on a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have one multidimensional array for which I want to apply the spread operator to get one array with no duplicate values. Here is the multidimensional array:

```
colorArray = [
['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Hematite'],
['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neutral'],
['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neon'],
['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neon'],
['Colorful Beaded Anklet', 'Fuchsia, Gold'],
['Colorful Beaded Anklet', 'Yellow'],
['Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets','Gold Theme']
]
```

When I flatten the array by applying a push operator, it is no longer a multidimensional array and it looks like this:

```
colorArray = 
[
  'Bead Link Layered Anklet',
  'Gold, Hematite',
  'Bead Link Layered Anklet',
  'Gold, Multi, Neutral',
  'Bead Link Layered Anklet',
  'Gold, Multi, Neon',
  'Bead Link Layered Anklet',
  'Gold, Multi, Neon',
  'Colorful Beaded Anklet',
  'Fuchsia, Gold',
  'Colorful Beaded Anklet',
  'Yellow',
  'Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets',
  'Gold Theme '
]
```

My problem is that I can only apply the spread operator if the array is flat but I want to preserve the structure so I don't want to flatten it. This is what I get when I apply the spread operator to the flat array:

```
unique = 
[
  'Bead Link Layered Anklet',
  'Cream, Gold',
  'Gold, Hematite',
  'Gold, Multi, Neutral',
  'Gold, Multi, Neon',
  'Colorful Beaded Anklet',
  'Fuchsia, Gold',
  'Yellow',
  'Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets',
  'Gold Theme'
]
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
['Bead Link Layered Anklet', ['Gold, Hematite', 'Gold, Multi, Neutral', 'Gold, Multi, Neon'],
['Colorful Beaded Anklet', ['Fuchsia, Gold', 'Yellow'],
['Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets','Gold Theme']
```

This is what I used to get rid of duplicates:

unique = [...new Set(colorArray)];

Comment: You want to group the array by the first elements?

Comment: Create an object whose keys are the first element and values are an array of the second elements. Then convert that array back to a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a simple one-liner like that. You need to write a loop that groups things by the key element.

Comment: Correction: I want the result to look like this:

['Bead Link Layered Anklet', ['Gold, Hematite', 'Gold, Multi, Neutral', 'Gold, Multi, Neon']],
['Colorful Beaded Anklet', ['Fuchsia, Gold', 'Yellow']],
['Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets',['Gold Theme']]

Comment: Edit the question to make corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103990/convert-a-key-value-array-with-duplicate-keys-into-array-of-object-with-unique-k):

```js
var colorArray = [
  ['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Hematite'],
  ['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neutral'],
  ['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neon'],
  ['Bead Link Layered Anklet', 'Gold, Multi, Neon'],
  ['Colorful Beaded Anklet', 'Fuchsia, Gold'],
  ['Colorful Beaded Anklet', 'Yellow'],
  ['Rhinestone Pave Chain Layered Anklets', 'Gold Theme']
];

let result = [...Object.values(
  colorArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
    var key = el[0],
      value = el[1];
    acc[key] = acc[key] || {
      key,
      values: []
    };
    if (!acc[key].values.includes(value))
      acc[key].values.push(value);
    return acc;
  }, {})).map(el => [el.key, el.values])];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It was hard to find but I finally found it.